# Parsing `-C8` to get value to option -C

Tags: bash, options

I want to parse -C8 to a bash function and get the numeric value in a variable.

I have seen argument parsing implementations for -C 8 and -C=8, but not for -C8.

```
 while (( $# > 0 )); do
   case $1 in
     ("-C") cnt="$2" ; shift ;;
     ("-C="*) cnt="${1#*=}" ; shift ;;
   esac
 done
```

But not how to handle `-C8`.

Comment: Read `man getopt getopts`. There are better ways to parse options.

Comment: `getopts` in tedious to use if you want long options.  And with `getopt`, people complain on portability.  Another problem with `getopt` is that it cannot handle multiples values in the form `-C 8 13`.

Comment: What uses `-C 8 13` that couldn't be satisfied by `-C "8 13"`? Easily parseable with `getopt`. I conquer `getopt` complexity is by using a `bash` template that does common setup, and uses `getopts` to parse my `--verbose`, `--help`, and `--debug` switches, something I require in all my scripts.

Comment: That's a good point.  So you use both `getopt` and `getopts` then?  Could you show an example.  I'd like to see them.

Comment: The same issue: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2021-11/msg00113.html

Comment: In [your mail to the `help-bash` list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2021-11/msg00117.html), you mention that you also need to support optional option-arguments and multiple option-arguments.  Is that not an issue here?

Comment: In [another email to the `help-bash` list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2021-11/msg00135.html) it seems as if your issue here has been resolved. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to post the answer, but the system would not accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you understand the code in the examples you cite, you should be able to modify one pretty easily:

```
 (-C*) cnt="${1#-C}" ; shift ;;
```

Comment: This would then be an additional one, that has to be inserted after `("-C="*)` and not before.